Overlay text over a PGF plot in a minipage
I use matplotlib to export plots in the pgf format, such that I can include it in LaTeX and have it be rendered crisp and beautiful.
I can use minipage to order the plots in a figure and create e.g. a 2 by 2 array of plots.
What I would like to do is add additional text over the figures, e.g., in the 2x2 plot array, labels a), b), c) and d).
I imagined, based on other posts, it would be possible with tikz.
However, I do not manage to get the tikzpicture to actually overlay the pgf plot, it always seems to be under it instead, and therewith hidden.
Example code (2x1 plots for simplicity):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

% ...and required for my type of images & plots for LaTeX
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% TikZ compilation performance
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 

\newcommand\mathdefault{\mathsf} % fix compatibility of matplotlib's pgf export

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            \resizebox{0.98\textwidth}{!}{
            \input{figures/fig1a.pgf}
            }
            \label{fig:1a}
    \end{minipage}
    % Fill the space in between
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
            \centering
            % textwidth is defined by the minipage
            \resizebox{0.98\textwidth}{!}{
            \input{figures/fig1b.pgf}

% here, of of my attempts to add a label, "b)"
% this gets rendered under the plot (in z-coordinates)
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node at (2, 2) {b)};
\end{tikzpicture}
% end attempt

            }
            \label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption of both sides. All the captions are optional.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Example pgf file can be found e.g. here.
Sketch of what I want to achieve:

Sure, you may argue, do this in Python when plotting. And I agree, in certain scenarios, that could be the better solution. However, let's assume I have to include these plots more than once, e.g. in different orders, or unlabelled in the appendix, etc., to make this objective even more relevant.
So: how can I add additional text over (in z-coordinates) my pgf plots?

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719026/151808

Two possibilities here to add text above your pgf pictures.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

% ...and required for my type of images & plots for LaTeX
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%% TikZ compilation performance
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 

\newcommand\mathdefault{\mathsf} % fix compatibility of matplotlib's pgf export
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (a) {\resizebox{0.98\textwidth}{!}{
        \input{example-pgf.pgf}
      }};
      \node [anchor=north west,font=\tiny] at ($(a.north west)+(2em,-1em)$) {\fbox{Text added with \LaTeX}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    % Fill the space in between
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
      \centering
      % textwidth is defined by the minipage
      \begingroup
      \AtEndEnvironment{pgfpicture}{\pgfnodebox{box1}[stroke]{\pgfxy(4,10)}{Text added with \LaTeX}{3pt}{4pt}}
      \resizebox{0.98\textwidth}{!}{
        \input{example-pgf.pgf}
        
        % here, of of my attempts to add a label, "b)"
        % this gets rendered under the plot (in z-coordinates)
%        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%          \node at (2, 2) {b)};
%        \end{tikzpicture}
        % end attempt
        
      }
      \endgroup
      \label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption of both sides. All the captions are optional.}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{figure}
  
  See \ref{fig:1b} and \ref{fig:1}.
\end{document}


The label/ref doesn't work without extra work.
Have a look at this question too…

Why do you need to use tikZ to add labels? Is subcaption package an option?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{label a\label{a}}
    [.49\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
    \subcaptionbox{label b\label{b}}
    [.49\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Caption of both sides. All the captions are optional.}
    \label{ab}
  \end{figure}
  
  See \cref{a} and \cref{ab}.
  
\end{document}

Without your pgf files, I used example images…

Edit
To have the subcaptions on top of the graphs, add the following line in the preamble (after loading the package):
\subcaptionsetup[figure]{position=top}


Thanks for your answer. I guess TikZ is not strictly required, but with your solution, the labels are still not on top (in z-coordinates) of the plots/figures, but below (in y-coordinates).

@BernhardWebstudio, does the edit answer the question?

thanks, but unfortunately not, no: this way, the label is on top in y-coordinates (i.e., it comes before the plot when reading from top to bottom), rather than in z-coordinates (i.e., overlaying the figure)

I really don't understand what you want. What do you mean by y and z coordinates? Please edit your question with a picture of what you need.

Ok, I will edit my question later. Simple example now, maybe that helps: in your example, I want these "A" and "B" you have, the large ones in the center of the picture, added in LaTeX (with some possibility to move them around, change text, ...).
